# Unable to get group policy for machine, remotely, without having logged in manually at least once

Tags: c#, powershell, winrm, group-policy

I have written a C# desktop application, using System.Management.Automation, that remotes over to machines in our network and does diagnostics to make sure that they are all configured per our organization's policies.

```
PSCredential Credentials = new PSCredential(Username, Password);
WSManConnectionInfo ThisConnection = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, ThisSystem.IpName, 5985, "/wsman",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", Credentials);

using (Runspace ThisRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ThisConnection))
{
    ThisRunspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell ThisShell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ThisShell.Runspace = ThisRunspace;
```

To get the banner, which is in the group policy, it does the following code to execute the powershell command

```
        ThisShell.Commands.Clear();
        ThisShell.AddScript("echo N | gpupdate /force");
        ThisShell.AddScript("gpresult /h c:\\Windows\\Temp\\gpdata.html /F");
        ThisShell.AddScript("type c:\\Windows\\Temp\\gpdata.html");
        List<String> GroupPolicy = ThisShell.Invoke().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Which should create that html file with the group policy data for that machine.  And it does, as long as I have manually logged into that machine, with the same credentials.  If I have not, I get nothing.  I run other powershell commands just like this and get the results just fine, but for some reason this command for getting the group policy will only work for machines where I have logged in manually (using remote desktop) at least once, and with thousands of servers to check, this is not an option.

I thought it might be that logging in manually created the home folder for the admin account I am using, but that can't be because I am getting the results of other powershell commands that I piped to files.  I thought it might be that logging in manually updated the group policy on that machine, but that also cannot be, I think, because I added the `gpupdate /force`, and it made no difference.

Any clues?

Comment: As `WSManConnectionInfo` should create a user profile (by default) by itself, what happens if you wait e.g. 30 minutes and invoke the command again on the same remote machine? I wonder whether this is a timing issue as it might take some time to create your user profile at first logon...

Comment: If the answers don't help, try to go to SuperUser, it might better fit there. It is indeed a programming question but I'm sure the problem itself relates to administration too.

Comment: I don't know if it fits your question, but maybe Impersonation can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for gpresult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpresult):

`Because you can apply overlapping policy settings to any computer or user, the Group Policy feature generates a resulting set of policy settings when the user logs on. gpresult displays the resulting set of policy settings that were enforced on the computer for the specified user when the user logged on.`

Since you are talking about enforcing policy on servers, which should not be expected to normally have a user logged in, perhaps you can try adding the `/scope computer` option to get just the machine policies, which should always be available.

Comment: Dude!  That is **very** promising.  I can't try it until I am back in the office tomorrow, but I'll go in early to give it a shot.  Can't wait... and you'll hear from me one way or the other.  Again, thanks!

Comment: Darn it!  It didn't work.  I think you are exactly right that the issue is that the RSoP (Resultant Set of Policies) is never created, because it is only created on user login.  But even with the scope limitation, I guess it is still looking at that RSoP and not seeing anything created yet.  Two options - find a different way to get the banner, other than `gpresult` (but I can't see how anything else would get around the issue of overlapping policies any better than gpresult and using the RSoP), or make my application generate a Remote desktop login.  Time to investigate that, I think.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I tested using remote `gpresult /S [system] /r /scope computer` on a computer where interactive use without scope caused an error due to never logging on, perhaps running it locally is causing a different issue?

Comment: @AgapwIesu I tested using `psexec` and had no problem with it working - are you sure your issue is still the same after adding `/scope computer`?

Comment: If I understand the System.Management.Automation library, and what I am doing with it, correctly, I am actually connecting to it and running gpresult locally on that system.  If I understand what you are telling me correctly, I would need to run gpresult, with the system parameter, from a different machine.  That is very doable.  I will give that a shot.

Comment: Maybe even running it locally, if I add both the system and the scope parameters...  I am in Chicago for a conference, but I gotta try this... I'll let you know.

Comment: We have this issue trying to prove compliance to our auditors. The other issue you will run into is that unless the user logs in again, the policy will get stale (not update).

Comment: @uSlackr Since we are talking about machine policies, I would think that the RSOP would update when the server is rebooted (at least once a month after patching hopefully) even if it isn't updated when GPO is applied.